# Conversion of a string to double C#

Tags: c#, double

I have an interesting problem with a specific conversion.
When I try to  convert the string `"0,3"` or `"0.3"`, according to the `UICulture`, to a `Double` value, the result is `0,29999999`. I have not yet found a solution, in order to receive the result `0,3`.

There is any way to have the same values after the conversion?

Comment: This has been asked many, many, many times.  `0.3` is not representable exactly as a double value because of the way decimal values are stored in a binary computer.

Comment: See Marc's answer. Of note perhaps, it's called floating point representation not presentation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`double` ***cannot represent*** every value. It guarantees to represent integers, but that is about it. If you need something more like "human" approximation of numbers, use `decimal`:

```
decimal val = decimal.Parse("0.3");
```

Note: `decimal` *also* doesn't represent every value - but the way it does the approximation tends to be more like how people expect numbers to work. In particular, `double` is virtually useless for things like currency.

Comment: A bit more detail provided by Jon Skeet [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/618596/18192).  Click the linked articles for an in-depth explanation.  The short answer is that `decimal` is in base 10, which matches 0.3.  `double` is in base 2, which does not.